# How do I disable screen updating while reformatting an Excel 2007 chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a chart with about 70,000 data points. When I format the axes or data series, Excel automatically updates the chart before I am finished editing the value. This is very slow (1+ minutes), even with my 3.30-GHz, 8-core, Windows 7 Enterprise machine with 8-GB of memory.

For example, if I want to change the line width from 2.25 to 1.5, every time I type or delete something, the chart updates.

Is there a way to disable screen updating while reformatting the Excel 2007 chart?

[image: Dialog box for formatting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no setting to disable the chart update while the formatting dialogs are shown. As a workaround, you could use a smaller data set while you are formatting the chart. Once you're happy with the look, assign the real data set.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have Automatic Calculations turned on. This function recalculates the entire workbook when any value is changed.

If set the calculation option to `Manual`, the workbook will not update until you tell it to.

[image]

You can press the `Calculate Now` button or press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

*Note: I am using 2010, so the image may not be exact.*

Comment: Yeah, tried that. I think my issue is caused by Excel redrawing the chart before I am finished changing a formatting value.